# C# Query with Linq for datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm using the data from imported Excel file, and I'm having problems with my query, i wonder if its needed a database or i can do it just by store the data on datatable and work with queries there.
I added the code of my button with the query on windows forms:

```
private void btnCompare1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                query = from dt1
                        join dt2 on dt1.TELEFONO equals dt2.TELEFONO
                        select new
                        {
                            dt1.FOLIO_FACTURA,
                            dt1.CONCEPTO,
                            dt1.FECHA_PUBLICACION,
                            dt1.PERIODO,
                            dt1.TELEFONO,
                            dt1.MONTO,
                            dt1.FECHA_MOVIMIENTO
                        };

                dataGridView3.DataSource = query;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: We can't tell you if you need a database. Whether you do doesn't primarily depend on what you're doing here but on the need to store data for longer than the lifetime of the application. Also, you need to elaborate on "problems with my query".

Comment: Thx for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LINQ syntax is like this

```
from row in table select /*something*/
```

you wrote:

```
from row select   /*something*/
```

so your query should look more like:

```
private void btnCompare1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                query = from row1 in dt1
                        join row2 in dt2 on row1.TELEFONO equals row2.TELEFONO
                        select new
                        {
                            row1.FOLIO_FACTURA,
                            row1.CONCEPTO,
                            row1.FECHA_PUBLICACION,
                            row1.PERIODO,
                            row1.TELEFONO,
                            row1.MONTO,
                            row1.FECHA_MOVIMIENTO
                        };

                dataGridView3.DataSource = query;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now i have this error:

Error CS1936 No implementation of the query pattern was found for the source type 'DataTable'. 'Join' was not found.

I review the directives already